# Reduce the blocking time caused by Cloudfront third party code

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, amazon-cloudfront, netlify, lighthouse

The is the top diagnostic listed that is affecting my lighthouse score when I run a test on [web.dev](https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-suddenlysask-com/xp7js676em?form_factor=mobile)

> Reduce the impact of third-party code Third-party code blocked the main thread for 1,000 ms
> Third-party code can significantly impact load performance. Limit the number of redundant third-party providers and try to load third-party code after your page has primarily finished loading. Learn how to minimize third-party impact.TBT
> Third-Party
>
> cloudfront.net
> 68 KiB
> 962 ms
> /bundles/9eedcd9….js(d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net)
>
> Google Analytics
> analytics     21 KiB
> 39 ms
> /analytics.js([www.google-analytics.com](http://www.google-analytics.com))

[image]

How can I fix this diagnostic problem and improve my lighthouse score?

These are all the dependencies that I am using

```js
"dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.18",
    "@loadable/component": "^5.15.2",
    "@pittica/gatsby-plugin-recaptcha": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/react-helmet": "^6.1.5",
    "@types/react-scroll": "^1.8.3",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "core-js": "^3.23.1",
    "emailjs-com": "^3.2.0",
    "gatsby": "^4.16.0",
    "gatsby-background-image": "^1.6.0",
    "gatsby-image": "^3.11.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-create-client-paths": "^4.9.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-google-analytics": "^4.16.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-google-fonts": "^1.0.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-graphql-loader": "^1.0.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^4.16.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-netlify": "^5.0.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-preconnect": "^1.3.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-purgecss": "^6.1.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^5.16.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-svg": "^3.1.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-root-import": "^2.0.8",
    "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^5.16.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^4.16.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "^5.16.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-typescript": "^4.16.0",
    "gatsby-remark-images": "^6.16.0",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^4.16.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^5.16.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^4.16.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.12.6",
    "jshint": "^2.13.4",
    "query-string": "^7.1.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.7",
    "resize-observer-polyfill": "^1.5.1",
    "sass": "^1.52.3",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
    "webpack": "^5.73.0"
  }
```

It is a gatsby website that I am saving to github and using netlify to put online. The website is [suddenlysask.com](https://suddenlysask.com)

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, you are loading the third-party scripts asynchronously . There is excellent documentation from Google lighthouse on how to load third-party scripts here https://web.dev/efficiently-load-third-party-javascript/ effectively

Comment: I don't even know what the script is. I think it might be something that Netlify uses, I couldn't find anything about cloudfront in my code though

Comment: I couldn't find the Cloudfront script on the home page of the website, is it loaded on only certain pages? Unless you manage to find the script's source and get rid of it.